# GridTraveler tabulation error making all elements of the table 0 in js

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming

this is the tabulated version of gridTraveler, where you output the number of ways one can travel from the top left to the bottom right corner in an m*n box, but you can only move down or right.

```
const gridTraveler = (m, n) => {
    const table = Array(m+1)
        .fill()
        .map(_ => Array(n+1).fill(0));
    
    table[1][1] = 1;

    for(let i=0; i<=m; i++){
        console.log(i + 'th row');
        for(let j=0; j<=n; j++){
            if (i===0 || j===0){
                //do nothing
            }else{
                table[i][j] = table[i-1][j] + table[i][j-1];
            }
            console.log(table[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return table[m][n];
}

console.log(gridTraveler(2, 3));
```

I've tested most parts of the code and they all work as intended, except for the line where i assign a value to table[i][j]. Forr some reason the for loop keeps making all elements 0, even though it should give the correct answer on paper. i've tried asking gpt and it says my code is correct. Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and you made a simple mistake. You should have used += instead of just =.

First of all since you are skipping the first row and column, your for loops can start from 1.
Then let's evaluate what your for loops are doing.

Your table looks like this on the start:

```
0 0 0 ...
0 1 0 ...
0 0 0 ...
...
```

Since you are skipping the first row and the first column, on the first occurrence where you change a value of the array's element, you are setting the array's element's value to:

```
//i = 1, j = 1
table[i][j] = table [i - 1][1] + table[1][j - 1];
//table[1][1] = 0 + 0;
```

And looking at the values from the table, that is 0. After that the whole table will be a bunch of 0s, so you will always get 0 as an answer.

Here is the whole code that should be working:

```
const gridTraveler = (m, n) => {
    const table = Array(m + 1)
        .fill()
        .map((_) => Array(n + 1).fill(0));

    table[1][1] = 1;

    console.log(table);

    for (let i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        console.log(i + "th row");
        for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            table[i][j] += table[i - 1][j] + table[i][j - 1];
            console.log(table[i][j]);
        }
    }
    console.log(table);
    return table[m][n];
};

console.log(gridTraveler(3, 4));
```